# SammyJS with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sammy.js

I have problems using Sammy with Angular.

I have this application module

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp', []).run(function (routes) {
    routes.run('#/');
});
```

And this service

```
appModule.factory('routes', function ($rootScope) {

    var routes = $.sammy(function () {

        this.get('#/room/:roomId', function () {
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('user has entered the room', {roomId: that.params['roomId']});
            }, 1000);

        });

    });

    return routes;
});
```

I need this `setTimeout` because I don't know when $rootScope is accessible. When I put low interval number in `setTimeout`, event doesn't broadcasted. One second interval works OK, but I don't want such ugly solutions. How can I be sure that $rootScope is ready and I can launch url handler function?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really 'need' to use Sammy

Have you tried using Angular's routing to get the parameters?

see

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

and

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeParams)

cheers
Stu

Comment: I 'need' lightweight routing system. In my case just broadcasting event is enough. But in $routeProvider I should use angular view, specify templateUrl, controller for this view etc. I don't need any views, just fire callback associated with url.