# Using AngularJS with Sammy instead of ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, sammy.js

In order to call general functions (*any* functions!) based on route parameters, I'm looking for information on how to replace ngRoute with [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) as the route provider for my entire app.

Is it possible? How do I configure it to make "regular" angular routing work as usual?

<sup>Note: I've previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761689/executing-a-callback-function-based-on-routes-in-angular-no-navigation), where the comments implied that what I want might not be possible without third party libraries, and I've seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918301/sammyjs-with-angularjs) about this exact topic (but the only answer there said "but why not use ngRoute?" - I've already concluded that ngRoute doesn't do what I need). We already use Sammy elsewhere in the project, so if we could use it instead of any other third party solution here, that would mean one less dependency...</sup>